# Visual Studio 2022 does not "start" application when debugging multiple projects

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2022

I have got an issue with `Visual Studio Code 2022`. Sometimes - not always - when debugging multiple projects in the same solution, one or more applications do not start.
When debugging console applications, VS opens a new coonsole window for each startup project.

Some of the console applications do not show any output. Moreover, the affected projects also do not hit any breakpoints at all.

This issue started with VS2022. The same code worked perfectly with VS2019. In the following screenshot it is shown the first `Console.WriteLine` did not even get executed (It looks to me as if main is never invoked).
[image]

I have already checked if a breakpoint in another project blocks debugging, but that is not the case.

Comment: If you see a console window then the process got started.  If it doesn't make it to Main() then there's Evil Code somewhere that prevents that process from making progress.  Every new release of VS triggers a rash of questions about this kind of problem, disable the installed anti-malware product to see if it is the cause.

Comment: Does your startup project belong to the same Program fille?

Comment: @HansPassant anti-malware is already disabled.

Comment: @BasilKosovan I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. But the code in the screenshot is what is getting executed (open console window). This application is one of two startup projects in my current configuration. The other one started without any issue. Stopping debugging and starting again usually fixes the issue. Since "no code" gets executed, I'm also sure there is no deadlock or other race condition.

Comment: Its not just you, I'm having the same problem with VS 2022 + multiple apps running. I tried adding a Console.WriteLine() as the first thing in main, and even that isn't hit when this happens. I think we just need to wait for someone to submit the issue to Microsoft to get it fixed.

Comment: Same here. Can't find any hint and I can only shutdown then try again until it works.

Comment: Did you solve this? Although reinstalled the VS, the issue did not solve.

Comment: Me too. It seemed to start with the vs2022 preview. I find that restarting the debug session usually wakes VS up. Just another VS bug it seems.

Comment: Same issue for me, can start either one of two console projects individually, but once I've set them both to start at the same time, the first one starts, then the second but the first then shuts down again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click on switch between available views and solutions which will show up project solution Icon, right click on the icon and update startup projects.
[VS 2022 locate startup project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riJ0T.png)

Answer (score 0):

sort of help is to pause the debug (break all) and then continue the debug (play button;)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).